# Wordpress REST API ignoring POST request from Google Apps Script when using 'Body'

Tags: json, google-apps-script, wordpress-rest-api, urlfetch

I am fiddling for the first time with REST APIs so my knowledge is very low.
I am using Google Apps Scripts to manage Wordpress data through REST API.

`POST` Requests are perfectly working when options are passed through the URL parameters, while they are ignored when using `body`.

I initially thought that this was due to some issues on the Wordpress endpoints, however, as sending requests using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) the calls are being processed correctly, I suppose data is being sent incorrectly from my Google Apps Script.

Postman will expose sent data, offering an option to generate code for a given language, therefore I have used Javascript `Fetch` as a starting point.

Following is the Postman-generated code, which is correctly processed by Wordpress:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer some-token-here");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "wordpress_google_apps_login=some-cookie-data-here");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "acf": {
    "class": "Nursery"
  }
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/442?context=edit&_fields=acf", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

With the above as a starting point, I have adapted code for Google Apps Script, as follows:

```
var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "acf": {
    "class": "Nursery"
  }
});

var requestOptions = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {'Authorization' : 'Bearer some-token-here',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
  'body': raw,
  'redirect': 'follow'
};


 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/442?context=edit&_fields=acf",requestOptions);
```

Google Apps Script will return a response with code `200`, but the requested modifications will not occur. Please notice that the code generated by Postman, uses `'Content-Type'`, while Google Apps Script should use `'ContentType'` parameter. I have tried both, with no success.

Are there some errors in the adapted code, or is there something missing, or even worst, Google Apps Script has some limitations or is it changing somehow the `POST` request in a way it is not correctly interpreted on the Wordpress end?

**EDIT**

A quick addition to @idfurw solution, is that it is also required to use 'Content-Type', as the request which includes 'ContentType' will be ignored!

Comment: You should use `payload` property for the POST body in GAS.

Comment: Man, you made my day! Post a reply and I will accept this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post the body, use `payload` property instead of `body` property.

Reference:

- examples of [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Advanced parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters)